# Create a new polygon from another one that is larger than the first by x meters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation

I have a set of polygons of different shapes and sizes in shapefile1.

What I need to do, is to create new polygons around the boundaries of the polygons in  shapefile1, larger by x meters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please ask one question per Question (it's the only way to avoid multiple partial answers, and improves response rate). A question like this needs to have a graphic to distiguish scaling from buffering. You should always specify the exact software  available, and for ArcGIS, the license level and available extensions. Please edit the question.

Comment: So, your suggestion is to divide this question in two different topics?

Comment: Unless you can rewrite it, three different questions, since point-in-poly may fail with irregular shapes.

Comment: So I edit this one for the first question and I create a new discussion for point 2&3

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215813/increase-each-polygon-area-to-the-same-area/215919#215919

Answer (score 2):

Use the buffer tool under geoprocessing menu. Input the first shapefile and state the distance you want. See the image attached. [image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The scale tool is exactly what I need, the problem is how can I say to arcmap to do this for "x meters" given that the only parameter that they ask to me is a "scale factor"

Answer (score 2):

Try Buffer geoprocessing.

You can find it under Geoprocessing\buffer, on buffer window specify the shapefile of exciting polygons and the distance(scale factor) you want to buffer around existing polygons.

Comment: Buffers have large holes inside each polygon. Not sure this is desired.

Comment: buffer, just buffer any feature on specified distance, if your feature have holes of couse it will maintain the first geometry so new features will be with holes. for details watch cwecU screenshots