# Buffering a polygon to match an area

Tags: python, gdal, polygon, ogr, shapely

I have a large polygon (A) with a specific area.
I also have another polygon (B) with area less than polygon A.

I want to buffer the polygon B so that its area becomes equal to the area of A.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
ulx,uly= -105.645292, 28.094511
lrx, lry = -101.985052, 24.885167
poly_A = Polygon([(ulx,uly),(ulx,lry),(lrx,lry),(lrx,uly)])
print (poly_A.area)


ulx,uly= -110.398408,  58.136267
lrx, lry = -108.689382,  57.137692
poly_B = Polygon([(ulx,uly),(ulx,lry),(lrx,lry),(lrx,uly)])
print (poly_B.area)


buffer_size = (poly_A.area - poly_B.area) / poly_B.length
print (buffer_size)

poly_C = poly_B.buffer(buffer_size)
print (poly_C.area)
```

After knowing `buffer_size`, I can get bufferred polygon C  with area equals to polygon A.

Note. All polygons dealt are `rectangles`.
Both polygons are in `latlon` coordinates

Comment: Its classic task for https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

Comment: is the algorithm implemented in shapely or python?

Comment: I used Python and arcgis buffer to solve it. I can find my solution if you are interested in my answers. But language doesn't matter, algorithm is universal and very simple and very fast.

Comment: okay, please send me; i'll translate with shapely buffer

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215813/increase-each-polygon-area-to-the-same-area

Comment: hmmm, arcpy code seems complex than i expected, i donot have arcgis license

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The .area in shapely is plane area, so we need to transform longitude, latitude (4326) to project spatial reference (e.g. 3857).
2. For rectangle, if the original size is a * b, area is A, buffer distance is X,  the buffer area B then:

```
B = A + 2 * (a + b) * X + pi * X * X   ----- (1)

2 * (a + b) = c = perimeter = poly_B.length

(1) => X = sqrt(c * c - 4 * (B - A) * PI) / (2 * PI)
```

```python
import pyproj
import math
from functools import partial
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import shape
from shapely.ops import transform

proj = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'), \
               pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:8858'))

ulx, uly= -105.645292, 28.094511
lrx, lry = -101.985052, 24.885167
poly_A = Polygon([(ulx, uly),(ulx, lry),(lrx, lry),(lrx, uly)])
print (poly_A.area)  # 11.746969282560011


poly_A_proj = transform(proj, poly_A)
poly_A_proj_area = poly_A_proj.area
print(poly_A_proj_area) # 129724395664.97488


ulx, uly= -110.398408, 58.136267
lrx, lry = -108.689382, 57.137692
poly_B = Polygon([(ulx,uly),(ulx,lry),(lrx,lry),(lrx,uly)])
print (poly_B.area)  # 39511382337.41971


poly_B_proj = transform(proj, poly_B)
poly_B_proj_area = poly_B_proj.area


buffer_size = (math.sqrt(poly_B.length * poly_B.length - 4*(poly_B.area - poly_A.area)*math.pi)-poly_B.length) / (2 * math.pi)
print (buffer_size)  # 1.122771717045914


poly_C = poly_B.buffer(buffer_size)
print (poly_C.area)  # 11.740610528262806
```

Comment: I tried according to you and edited the question. Unfortunately, I did not get expected result

Comment: Sorry. I think you can project the polygon first and then calculate the area.

Comment: how can i project?

Comment: Both polygons are in latlon coordinates

Comment: And both polygons are rectangles, so a different trick, rather than .buffer, should work, as output is enlarged polygon

Comment: I update the python scripts. This is for rectangles. Note: area in shapely is plane area.

Comment: Can you explain what the equation of buffer_size is doing?

Comment: Updated. As the polygon is rectangle, there is no overlaps between buffers. So we can calculate the buffer distance directly.

Comment: Don't use epsg:3857 for measurements it distorts area by latitude!

Comment: Correct. Update to EPSG: 8858 (WGS 84 / Equal Earth Americas)

Comment: @IanTurton Which epsg is better for Asia for this purpose?

Comment: @Luo You did not use projected coordinates in your equation, why?