# Subdividing a polygon around a point in R or ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, polygon, arcgis-pro, point

I am trying to create a 5ha plot around a point within a permissions layer. The permissions layer doesn't always extend 5ha around the point in a square so I cannot clip it. I would like to automate this process.

My current approach is to clip 5ha around the points and then use those where it creates a full square.

[image]

Then Use the subdivide polygon tool in ArcGIS Pro and use the polygons where the point is mostly in the centre.
[image]

Then draw the 5ha manually for the rest of the polygons.

[image]

Is there a way to automate this process in R? I've only found how to subdivide the polygon into equal areas.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please choose either ArcGIS or R as the focus of your question, the [Edit] it to indicate what you have tried. Note that squares with a fixed area will only appear square in an appropriate projection.

Comment: Now that this has an ArcMap answer I think you should ask new separate questions for R and ArcGIS Pro, if you still need those questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this is near identical to [Creating buffers of specific size](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209047/creating-buffers-of-a-specific-size-and-shape/209115#209115).
It is about iterations... Script below assumes that you have initial squares layer (clone) and its' table has reference to limiting polygon OID:

[image]
[image]

Adjust naming of layers in your map to match ones in a script and run it from Python window.

```
d = arcpy.Describe("PARENT")
SR = d.spatialReference
parentShapes = {oid:shp for oid,shp in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("PARENT",["OID@","SHAPE@"])}
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("clone",["SHAPE@","AREA_M2","ORIG_FID"]) as cursor:
    for shp,target,parent in cursor:
        parentPgon = parentShapes[parent]
        cPoint = arcpy.PointGeometry(shp.centroid,SR)
        middle = pow(target,0.5)/2
        low = middle; high = middle*10
        while True:
            middle=0.5*(low+high)
            square = cPoint.buffer(middle).extent.polygon
            isect = square.intersect(parentPgon,4)
            if (high - low) < 0.001: break
            curArea = isect.area
            if curArea<target:low=middle
            else:high=middle
        cursor.updateRow((isect,target,parent))
```

Output:

[image]

[image]